# Which parts of Meschta Shabbos have a connection to Hilchos Shabbos in Shulchan Aruch

Tags: shabbat, shulchan-aruch, maseches-shabbos

I'm interested in learning Meschta Shabbos אליבא דהילכתא with Shulchan Aruch. I would like to know how many pages in the meschta are relevant to Hilchos Shabbos in Shulchan Aruch. It doesn't need to be an exact answer with every daf just in general which sugyos are connected to Hilchos Shabbos.

For example the chapter הזורק speaks about domains, which are discussed in hilchos eiruvin, so that chapter would not be on the list. However, chapter five במה בהמה speaks anout things an animal can go out with on Shabbos is connected to siman 305 in Shulchan Aruch (besides last two daf which are agadah)

Comment: It might be easier to check yourself than to get a full answer here. If you have a newer gemara, there may be a complete Ein Mishpat in the back that quotes all relevant Shulchan Aruch seifim for each daf. You can check it there. If not, just check the Ein Mishpat on each daf and find the dapim whose Win Mishpat quotes hilchos Shabbos.

Comment: It doesnt work like that. If you learn halocho you have to learn the whole siman even those that are not in mesechta shabbos. Many are from brochos like. If you learn gemoro you can miss out what isnt about shabbos like tumah.

Comment: @Yehuda  I'm curious to see the opposite, which parts of Meschta Shabbos are relevant to shulchan aruch. (@interested I want to go through the entire shulchan aruch just not the entire gemoro). I could go through each daf but besides the fact that it would take a long time, I also want to get a general overview of the Meschta and I feel like I would be missing that since I didn't learn the Meschta yet.

Comment: In that case, you can do a "reverse look-up" by going through the shulchan aruch and checking the be'er hagolah on each se'if.

Answer (score 1):

If you're goal is to go through Shulchan Aruch while looking up the Gemaros, the best source would be the Be'er Hagolah on each individual halacha, printed in all standard sets of Shulchan Aruch and Mishnah Berurah.

The Beis Yosef on the Tur quotes the Gemaros and relevant Rishonim.

However, I don't think you can really get the same understanding from seeing all the individual gemaros without their originial context. I personally would suggest learning through the Rif, who quotes the parts of Shabbos relevant to Halacha.

[Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/explore-Bavli-and-Shulchan-Arukh/Shabbat/Shulchan-Arukh,-Orach-Chayim) also has a searchable graphic connecting gemara to Shulchan Aruch, but it does not seem to be working currently.